# Can't figure out how to 'merge' these two for loops together to maximize productivity | Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to make it so that both of these if statements make use of the same for loop somehow since it has been very painful having to copy-paste updated code to the other for loop whenever I make changes (since they both use literally the exact same code). So if I can get them to share for loops, I could cut out a thousand lines of unnecessary code from the script. It's also making my visual studio code lag. The code logic is very similar to this, but this is scaled down.

Essentially I want to have 2 modes, automatic and manual. With the automatic, it'll automatically use the `my_list` as the default and I won't have to enter specific variables. Whereas in the manual I do have to input each and every variable.

```
my_list = ['apple','orange','nuts','fruits','things']

mode = 'M apple orange'
mode = mode.split(' ')

if 'M' == mode[0]:
    for item in mode[1:]:
        print(item)

if 'A' == mode[0]:
    for item in my_list:
        print(item)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not using a ternary operator here?

```
my_list = ['apple','orange','nuts','fruits','things']

mode = 'M apple orange'
mode = mode.split(' ')

used_list = mode[1:] if ('M' == mode[0]) else my_list

for item in used_list:
    print(item)
```

Comment: Nice... This answer has only `1 for loop` as per the author's question and is compact.

Answer (score 0):

Define a method that process the list:

```py
def process(items):
    for item in items:
        print(item)

my_list = ['apple','orange','nuts','fruits','things']

mode = 'M apple orange'
mode = mode.split(' ')

if 'M' == mode[0]:
    process(mode[1:])

if 'A' == mode[0]:
    process(my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the desired list in a new variable and use that in the for loop

```
my_list = ['apple','orange','nuts','fruits','things']

mode = 'M apple orange'
mode = mode.split(' ')
if mode[0] == 'A':
    used_list = my_list
else:
    used_list = mode[1:]

for item in used_list:
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just make a function with a default value.

If the function is called without an argument, it will use the default list.
If the function is called with an argument, it will overwrite the default:

```
def my_function(list_1: list = ['apple','orange','nuts','fruits','things']):
      pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary?

```
d = {'M':mode[1:], 'A':my_list}

for i in d[mode[0]]: 
    print(i) # Instead of loop, print(*d[mode[0]], sep='\n')
```

Or this:

```
toprint = []
if 'M' == mode[0]:
    toprint = mode[1:]
elif 'A' == mode[0]:
    toprint = my_list
print(*toprint, sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```py
my_list = ['apple','orange','nuts','fruits','things']

mode = 'M apple orange'
mode = mode.split(' ')

flag = mode[0]
if flag not in ('M', 'A'):
    pass  # exit or something

source = my_list if flag == 'A' else mode[1:]
for item in source:
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could just do something like this, I suppose:

```
my_list = ['apple','orange','nuts','fruits','things']

mode = 'M apple orange'
mode = mode.split(' ')

# You can of course simplify this if-statement if you do only need the two 
# modes

if mode[0] == 'M':
    selected_list = mode
    start = 1
elif mode[0] == 'A':
    selected_list = my_list
    start = 0
else:
    pass

# Then the for loop

for item in selected_list[start:]:
    print(item)
```